# Psycopg2 converting date string to previous day

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm using `psycopg2` to insert some data into a PostgreSQL database.

### What I'm doing:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="127.0.0.1", port='5432', database="mydatabase", user="root", password="root")
cursor = conn.cursor()

# MY-SQL-FILE has a bunch of INSERT statements, such as:
# INSERT INTO mytable (mydate) values ('1991-18-03');

cursor.execute(open("/MY-SQL-FILE.sql").read())
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

### What I end up with

Executing the above script will create a row in my database where the date is: `1991-03-17 21:00:00`

Obs: The field type of `mydate` is `timestamptz`

### What I expected

I expected to get a row where the date were `1991-03-18 00:00:00`

Funny thing is if I try to execute the same insert statement into DBeaver I get `1991-03-18 00:00:00`

### What I want to know

Why is this happening? (it most likely will work if I convert the date from string to datetime)

But I want to know why this happens, where does this 21:00:00 comes from, if it were a DB TZ problem the time would not be the same everytime I think...

Comment: What is the schema/field type for mytable/mydate?

Comment: the type is `timestamptz`

Comment: *shrug* well, some sort of time zone conversion is going on. Chances are, PostgreSQL is defaulting to UTC, since your file is not inserting time zoned values and you are 3 hours away from UTC. What does `show timezone;` tell you if you run it from psql?

Comment: @MadWombat I logged into my container and via psql it showed: TimeZone 
----------
 UTC
(1 row)
On DBeaver it shows: America/Sao_Paulo

Comment: You figured it out Mad Wombat... Psycopg2 generates a UTC date and when it tries to insert it into my database the database itself converts it to the database timezone, which is America/Sao_Paulo and is -03:00UTC. Since UTC it was 00:00:00, it shows 21:00:00 from the previous day.